# In Flutter how store data's From database to the list

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, sqflite

I want Store many data's to the list in flutter from sqflite with bloc.

so i create a bloc function to do that

every things it's okay because I test them with different functions
but in bloc(#1)

bloc always return null to state

help me if You Know what's wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qx9t.png)

i test the database handler(#5) with future builder and then i removed the

Future builder because i want use bloc for build the database List

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Please never use photos of code, insert the code.